# Finding the diagonal from a collapsed 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, diagonal

I have a 3D vectors `v`.

```
A = rand(2, 2, 2);
v = sum(A, 2);
```

Now I simply did:

```
B = diag(v);
Error using diag
First input must be 2D.
```

With loop, I did the following:

```
for i = 1:2
   B{i} = diag(v(:, :, i));
end
```

I would like to get a 3D matrices from my 3D vectors. Suppose I have the following vector:

```
v(:, :, 1)=[1 2 3]';
v(:, :, 2)=[1 2 4]';
%I would like to get, using some command and without loop (if possible), a 3D matrix B
B(:, :, 1)=[1 0 0; 
            0 2 0; 
            0 0 3];
B(:, :, 2)=[1 0 0;
            0 2 0;  
            0 0 4];
```

Comment: Could you explain your desired outcome? To avoid the error using diag, you can try diag(squeeze(v))

Comment: Look at he `squeeze` function

Comment: Do you want to create a 3D diagonal that slices through the cube with out the `for` loop?

Comment: @kkuilla yes that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am just assuming from your your final lines in the question that you have `v` and you are looking to  get `B` without loops. For the same, I think this would work for you -

```
%// Input
v(:, :, 1)=[1 2 3]';
v(:, :, 2)=[1 2 4]';

[M,~,P] = size(v)
B = zeros(size(v,1),size(v,1),size(v,3));
B(bsxfun(@plus,[1:M+1:M*M]',[0:P-1]*M*M)) = v %//'
```

Output -

```
B(:,:,1) =
     1     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     0     3
B(:,:,2) =
     1     0     0
     0     2     0
     0     0     4
```

Comment: Thanks! I am gonna save the world now! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
result = arrayfun(@(k) diag(v(:,:,k)), 1:size(v,3), 'UniformOutput', false);
result = cat(3, result{:});
```

Or, if you want it in one line, use `cell2mat` and `reshape` instead of `cat`:

```
result = reshape(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) diag(v(:,:,k)), 1:size(v,3), 'UniformOutput', false)), size(v,1), size(v,1), size(v,3));
```